# Error in registering the user in my note taking web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

When i run the application in chrome and try to register by putting the user details, it shows this error in console : `internal server error occured`.
I guess it is of register controller function but I can't figure what's wrong with it.

This is my register router and function:

```js
router.post('/createuser', [
  body('name', 'Enter a valid name').isLength({min: 3}),
  body('email', 'Enter a valid email').isEmail(),
  body('password', 'Password must be atleast 5 characters').isLength({min: 5}),
], async (req, res) => {
  let success = false

  //if there are errors return bad request and the errors
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).send({success, errors: errors.array()});
  }

  //check whether the user with same email exists already
  try {

    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})

    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        success,
        message: 'Sorry a user with this email already exists'
      })
    }

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    const secPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt)
    req.body.password = secPass
    const newUser = new User(req.body)
    await newUser.save()

    res.status(201).send({
      success: true,
      message: "Registered successfully"
    })
    //catch errors
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message)
    res.status(500).send({
      success: false,
      message: "Internal server error occured"
    })
  }

})
```

This is my register page code:

```
const Signup = (props) => {
const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({ name: "", email: "", password: "", cpassword: "" })
let navigate = useNavigate()

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const { name, email, password } = credentials
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/createuser", {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, email, password })
    });
    const json = await response.json()
    console.log(json)
    if (json.success) {
        props.showAlert("Accouct Created Successfully ", "success")
        navigate("/login")

    }
    else {
        props.showAlert("Invalid credentials", "danger")
    }

}
const onChange = (e) => {
    setCredentials({ ...credentials, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}

return (
    <div className='container mt-3'>
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="my-3">
                <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label"><MdDriveFileRenameOutline style={{ "marginRight": "3px" }} /> Name</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="name" name='name' aria-describedby="emailHelp" onChange={onChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="email1" className="form-label"><MdEmail style={{ "marginRight": "3px" }} />Email address</label>
                <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" name='email' aria-describedby="emailHelp" onChange={onChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label"> <RiLockPasswordFill style={{ "marginRight": "3px" }} />Password</label>
                <input type="password" className="form-control" id="password" name='password' onChange={onChange} minLength={5} required />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="cpassword" className="form-label"><RiLockPasswordFill style={{ "marginRight": "3px" }} />Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" className="form-control" id="cpassword" name='cpassword' onChange={onChange} minLength={5} required />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
)
}
export default Signup
```

Server.js code :

```
const connectToMongo = require('./db')
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')

connectToMongo()

const app = express()
const port = 5000

app.use(cors({
   origin: ['http://localhost:3000']
}))
app.use(express.json())

app.use('/api/auth', require("./routes/auth"))
app.use('/api/notes', require("./routes/notes"))

app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`iNotebook backend app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Mongoose model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose

const UserSchema = new Schema({
   name: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   email: {
       type: String,
       required: true,
       unique: true
   },
   password: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   date: {
       type: Date,
       default: Date.now
   }

 });
 const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema)

 module.exports = User
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In your code, what is the output of `console.error(error.message)`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs is says : POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/createuser 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: What happens if you change all occurrences of `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs it  says :   POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth/createuser net::ERR_FAILED Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Could a firewall or proxy be blocking requests? If you run the app with debugging enabled, are there more clues in the log?

Comment: @rickhg12hs no it only shows this error : Signup.js:14     POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/createuser  500 (internal server eror) {success: false, message: 'Internal server error occured'}